# Generate source code from eclipse sirius

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, eclipse-sirius

Using eclipse Sirius, we can create our own graphical modeling workbench.

I read about Sirius tutorials from the following link.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Sirius/Tutorials/StarterTutorial

After completing the above tutorial, I got xml file that is related to my sirius editor.

The question is how can I export soruce code or project from sirius xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to generate any source code for your modeler defined with Sirius. The "XML file" (the one with the `.odesign` extension) **is** your modeler's definition. It is interpreted dynamically by Sirius, no Java code is generated from it. Once you have your modeler's definition, if you want to distribute it to your users you simply have to package it as a proper Eclipse plug-in. https://wiki.eclipse.org/Sirius/Tutorials/UpdateSiteTutorial describes the steps needed for this if you're not familiar with Eclipse plug-in development.

Comment: And what if you want to add customization by modifying the source files such as `EditPart`s, provider classes or any other classes from the GMF world?